# How to port function names from one exe to another?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

I have two 64 bit elf files for one program but with 2 different version.
IDA can resolve the function names in one of them while not for the other.
I don't have bindiff but I want an automatic solution like this tool if available

Answer (score 3):

You can try and use [Diaphora](https://github.com/joxeankoret/diaphora). It is open source, and is probably the best Bindiff alternative out there.
That said, be aware that binary diffing might fail in many cases regardless of the tools used.

Comment: In addition to Diaphora, here are several more diff'ing tools: http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:Executable_Diff_Tools